# Custom Taxonomy Term Template

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I would like to use a custom template for my taxonomy term pages. 
I attempted doing so by creating a hook in template.php like so

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables){
    if($hook == 'node'){
        if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy'){
            $vars['template_file'] == 'node-taxonomy';
        }
    }
}
```

And then creating a custom template called node-taxonomy.tpl.php

However the page does not change.

I understand that I can achieve something similar using views, but since other sites are using different themes on our drupal instance I'd prefer not to change anything that relies on those views.

Comment: Your PHP code is incorrect in multiple places. What are you trying to do - provide custom templates for `node.tpl.php` or `page.tpl.php` on taxonomy pages?

Comment: Yes that is the intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

- taxonomy-term--tid.tpl.php
- taxonomy-term--vocabulary-machine-name.tpl.php
- taxonomy-term.tpl.php

Note that underscores in a vocabulary's machine name are replaced by hyphens.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a template for a specific taxonomy term view mode without display suite? I used hook_entity_info_alter to add a view mode to taxonomy terms. Now i need to assign a template to that view mode?

Answer (score 1):

In addition and for those who need, you can provide template suggestions for taxonomy terms that way :

```
function hook_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {
  $term = $vars['elements']['#taxonomy_term'];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($vars['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->bundle() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->id() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $sanitized_view_mode;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

It will provide, e.g. :

```
"taxonomy_term__vocabularyname__teaser"
"taxonomy_term__257__teaser"
"taxonomy_term__teaser"
```